# Authenticating, using and reusing password and Kerberos credentials in Java

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, jaas, jackrabbit

Warning: This is an extremly long post, simply because I don't know how to explain our specific problems any other way (sorry).

Short version:

We are building a very modular suite of Java applications (both client and server side). Some clients have to authenticate against the servers, and the servers can authenticate against different types of user stores. Servers can also call other servers on behalf of their authenticated user, i.e. using their credentials. This has worked fine so far using simple username/password credentials, but now we have to optionally support SSO via Kerberos (and later other authentication systems). So far, we're failing (partly miserably).

Long version:

Our central Java library for handling principals is called User Access Layer (UAL). This library is used by both client and server applications and provides three types of funcationality:

1. Authenticate users based on their credentials (results in a failed authentication or basic information about the user, i.e. at least a login name or ID)
2. Perform principal queries
3. Perform principal modifications in the user store, if the backend supports it

(2) and (3) can be performed either using credentials specified by the caller or (if the backend supports it) as a technical user.

Actual access to the user store is handled by the configured backend. We provide a number of backends (LDAP, WebDAV, a custom JDBC database, a custom XML file) which can all be configured through a unified configuration file, usually named useraccess.xml. This file defines which backend (or backends) should be used and how it is configured, e.g. LDAP server and structure data for the LDAP backend or the database URL and database user credentials for the database backend. All backends implement the same interfaces so the application code is independent from the backends configured for a particular installation.

In our product, UAL is used by two different types of applications:

1. Clients (both command line/desktop clients and web frontend applications opened by a user in a browser). These applications use UAL to perform principal queries (e.g. our file browser application when modifying the ACLs of a WebDAV resource) or principal modifications (we have a web based user management application). Depending on the application, they get the credentials used for their UAL operations in one of the following ways:
   a. User provides the credentials on the command line when calling the application
   b. Application opens a dialogue and prompts the user to input credentials when a server access requires them
   c. A login screen displayed when the user first accesses a web frontend application
2. Servers. which use UAL to:
   a. Authenticate a user based on the credentials provided via the used protocol (e.g. HTTP/WebDAV or SOAP/WSSE)
   b. Perform authorization for a user based on the user's (or the user's groups') attributes
   c. Perform UAL operations (queries/modifications) on behalf of the client
   d. Call other servers on behalf of the client, i.e. passing another server the user's credentials (e.g. via HTTP/WebDAV or SOAP/WSSE)

Until now, all our credentials were user name/password pairs, which worked fine as long as we made sure to keep these credentials in the user's session where necessary to later use them for accessing another server. We could do that every call that retrieved credentials or passed them to a server went through some of our code which could store/provide the necessary credentials.

Everything has become much more complicated with the requirement to support SSO via Kerberos. We've tried several approaches and modified our code base several times, but every time we believe to be on the right track, we realise that there's one spot we overlooked which cannot work the way we intended.

What makes things so confusing is that we have to handle credentials in several different ways. These are some of the ways we have to provide credentials to a server:

1. Via Apache HttpClient when accessing a HTTP/WebDAV server
2. Via SOAP/WSSE when accessing a web service
3. Via JNDI when accessing the LDAP server (in UAL)

And some of the ways we have to receive and verify credentials from a client:

1. As a login module in Apache Jackrabbit
2. When receiving a SOAP/WSSE message in one of our JAX-WS web services

A very common use case for us is the following:

1. Client calls server A via SOAP, providing credentials
2. Server A retrieves the credentials from the SOAP message and verifies them (responds with an error if they are invalid (authentication error) or the user is not authorized to perform the desired operation (authorization error))
3. Server A then calls WebDAV server B on behalf of the user, passing the user's credentials so that the WebDAV operation can be carried out with that user's permissions (and using that user's name and other attributes)
4. Server B retrieves the credentials from the HTTP message and verifies them
5. Server B then performs a principal query on the user store C, passing the user's credentials to the user store (depending on the configured UAL backend, this may simply compare the user's name and password to those in the user store XML file, or use them to establish an LDAP connection and query the LDAP store as that user)

And the problem is: There seems to be very little information on the internet to help with our specific problems. For starters, most resources simply describe how to setup a JAAS configuration file for a container to let its web applications perform user authentications. But our code has to run on both clients and servers and use one configuration file to specify the user store config for both authentication and principal queries/modifications. Furthermore, this has to work, with the same code, with user name/password credentials against a variety of user stores (some of them custom written) and with Kerberos (and later other) tickets against an LDAP server. And finally, it's not enough to have an authentication library which reliably tells us that user has provided the correct credentials (as many JAAS login modules seem to do), since we actually have to keep the user's credentials for further calls.

Since Apache Jackrabbit, which is the base for one of our core components, needs us to configure a JAAS login module, and there already are JAAS login modules for LDAP and Kerberos authentication, we have successfully modified UAL to perform all its authentication tasks via JAAS. For this we had two write login modules for our custom backends, and I had to implement my own LDAP login module since the default JAAS one would successfully authenticate the user against the LDAP server, but then throw away both the user's credentials and the LDAP context, so we couldn't perform further LDAP query using the same credentials. All our own login modules store the credentials in the authenticated subject's private credentials set, which is what JAAS's default Kerberos login module does as well. Using the resulting subject, we can then perform user queries. This works with all our backends and with both passwords and Kerberos tickets.

We were also able to modify our SOAP services to extract the credentials from the SOAP message. In the case of password credentials, we can simply pass them to JAAS when the authentication callback asks for credentials. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to do the same with a Kerberos ticket. Instead, our SOAP services currently handle those on their own, passing them through the necessary GSS API calls to verify the ticket, retrieve a matching ticket for the SOAP service's configured service user, and create a Subject containing the credentials and user information. Using this subject, we can then perform queries/modifications through UAL. However, this not only means that our SOAP services completely bypass UAL when authenticating Kerberos tickets, they also need some Kerberos configuration data (the service user name, the realm and the keytab file) in their own configuration, in addition to the useraccess.xml which already contains the same data (but not directly accessible to a generic UAL client because these settings are specific to the UAL LDAP/Kerberos backend). Obviously, things will only get worse when we add support for other ticket based authentication methods and they also have to be manually implemented in each SOAP service in addition to the UAL backend that actually handles the user store access.

Worst of all, we're still unsure how to get all this into our Jackrabbit based WebDAV server. Jackrabbit needs a login module, which should be fine for handling user name/password credentials but (as far as we can tell) fail for Kerberos tickets. We could probably fetch those manually from the HTTP headers, but that won't stop Jackrabbit from calling the login module and the login module from failing because it will still ask for a password and then fail to authenticate against Kerberos without one.

I can't shake the feeling that either our approach or (quite possibly) our understanding of how all these pieces should fit together is fundamentally flawed, but nothing we can find on the net spans enough of our requirements to indicate what we're doing wrong (or, more importantly, how it should be done to make it right). Because of the complexity of even describing our problems I so far shied away from posting this as a question, but if you've read this far and can give us any pointers on how to resolve this, you could save us from weeks of frustration.

Comment: *"services completely bypass* [our custom auth system] *when authenticating Kerberos tickets ... they also need some Kerberos configuration"* -- well, that's the whole point: Single-Sign-On using a single back-end system, i.e. the Kerberos KDC. Too bad for components that do not support Kerberos out-of-the-box, and for components relying on the Java implementation, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html Bottom line: Kerberos is fine when hidden under the Microsoft proprietary implementation; otherwise it's indeed *"Madness beyond the Gate"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove everything after

> Until now, all our credentials were user name/password pairs, which worked fine as long as we made sure to keep these credentials in the user's session where necessary to later use them for accessing another server. We could do that every call that retrieved credentials or passed them to a server went through some of our code which could store/provide the necessary credentials.

You problem is plain simple: **you need credential delegation with Kerberos**. The basic technique is quite simple. Since you have multiple problem areas here, I would recommend to break them up to have you problem solved:

1. OS/environment configuration for Kerberos credential delegation
2. How to request a delegable service token
3. How to retrieve the delegated TGT from the client
4. How to reuse the TGT from the client and request another service token

Since your inbound channel is HTTP, here are the answers:

1. If you are in an Active Directory environment, request your admin to set "trusted for delegation" on the machine account which will accept the GSS security context.
2. This is a bit tricky because it depends on the client language and library. In Java it is as simple as setting [`GSSContext.requestCredDeleg(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/ietf/jgss/GSSContext.html#requestCredDeleg(boolean)). Eloborate on the rest.
3. Inspect the code of my [Tomcat SPNEGO/AD Authenticator library](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/), I am extracting the client's TGT and storing it in the `Principal` implementation served by `HttpServletRequest#getPrincipal` method.
4. Assuming that your backend client library supports GSS-API properly, there are basically two ways to do it: (1) explicit credential usage: pass the delegated `GSSCredential` instance to the client lib and it should the rest. (2) implicit: Wrap your client action in a `PrivilegedAction`, construct a `Subject` with the private `GSSCredential` and invoke `Subject.doAs` with both. JAAS will use the implicit credential from the thread's subject and perform the operation on behalf of your user.

It seems like you haven't even reached point 2 or 3 yet.

Comment: Thanks for this overview. I believe I was mostly on the right track, but your comment helped me understand the whole thing better, and more importantly helped me see where our approach was right and where it wasn't.

Most importantly, we now really handle Kerberos authentication separately from regular callback authentication, and all code that uses it first checks if Kerberos credentials are available or if it should try to fall back to configured callback credential providers.

Comment: Additionally, setting our own password credentials in the subject for non-Krb stuff allows us to still delegate credentials the hard way (by carrying the passwords along all the way) in our intermediate services where necessary if Kerberos is not an option.

Comment: @MarianSchedenig, I am glad you where able to resolve the issue. Grüße nach Wien.